# Obtaining safeAreaInsets for interface orientations?

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, safearealayoutguide

I am using `safeAreaInsets` to respect iPhone X's notch and reserved menu areas.

This works great for when loading the view since the view is in the current interface orientation.

However, I need to know what the future values will be to handle animation in my willRotate method. `UIViewController` has a `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` method, but that isn't updated until after the device has rotated. I need something like `viewSafeAreaInsetsWillChange`, but of course does not exist.

So, it seems that the only way to handle the animations in my willRotate method is by hard coding the safe area values, which is certainly far from ideal.

Is there anyway to obtain safe areas for a given orientation (portrait or landscape)?